# How do I get rid of Oracle Archive (.arc) files?

Tags: oracle, archive

Oracle archive files are about to bring my production dbase to a grinding halt. The application is depositing one ~100MB .ARC files daily. 
How can I compress these .arc files or delete them? 
I'm running running Oracle 10.2 with admin privileges. 
I work in SQL Server so am out of my comfort zone here.

Answer (score 1):

The backup process will handle your archived log files.
The best tool for the job is RMAN - Oracle Recovery Manager.

This will make your *.arc files go away:

On your host:

```
$rman target /
# datafiles and archived log files
RMAN>backup database pluss archivelog delete input;  
# archivelog files only
RMAN>backup archivelog all delete input; 
RMAN>show all; -- inspect the configuration. (Where the backup default is going)
```

Comment: I'm getting an insufficient privileges error when running rman from the command line so I guess i'm not an admin on this Oracle instance - can you tell me where this permission is setup in Oracle?

Comment: You need to be a member of ORA_DBA group.

Answer (score 0):

These are redolog file backups, needed to recover the database in case of disk or media failure. You can learn more here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/archredo.htm

You mention this is a production database, so I assume you generate backups at least once a day. If you use RMAN for your backups, you can use RMAN to purge old or obsolete redolog files, and even set a retention policy to automatically delete obsolete redolog files after some time. You can learn how here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/maint003.htm#i1006294

Comment: Is there a way to access Recovery Manager without the Enterprise Console Web interface? This instance of Oracle is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 & the Enterprise Console isn't configured. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can, typing RMAN in a command line the same way you would access SQL*PLUS. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96566/rcmcnctg.htm Now, it worries me that this is a "production" database, and apparently no back-ups are set. You should ask your DBA or sysadmin before trying anything on this database.